# What does int (abc)(int,int) mean?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, declaration

I am trying some random declarations of array pointers and function pointers together. I was struck here.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
int add(int a,int b){ 
    return 1729; }
int main(){
    int (abc)(int,int);
    abc = add;
    return 0;
}
```

The emitted error is:

```
cannot convert 'int(int, int)' to 'int(int, int)' in assignment
```

But as both `abc` and `add` are of the same type, why should it convert? Or is it possible to assign functions to new variables? If so, how to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do function pointers in C work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work)

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: You need `int (*abc)(int,int);` for `abc` to be a *function pointer* of the appropriate type.

Comment: More related to your problem, when asking about build errors, always copy-paste (as text) the full and complete error output into the question body. There might be details that you miss if you rewrite just a small part of the message.

Comment: `lvalue required as left operand of assignment`. You cannot assign a function to another function

Comment: Lastly, in C++ I really recommend you avoid pointers to functions. If you need a callable object use [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) instead.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, with `std::function` you pay for type erasure, with a function pointer you don't.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
int (abc)(int,int);
```

It's not a function pointer. The extra parentheses don't matter in this case, and it's equivalent to

```
int abc(int,int);
```

Which is a function *declaration*, that C++ allows you to put almost anywhere (like the body of another function). Your code doesn't compile because you attempt to assign one function name to another.

To get a pointer, you need pointer syntax

```
int (*abc)(int,int);
```

Where, this time, the parentheses *are* required, else you get a function declaration with an `int*` return type! And now the assignment will be well-formed.